# script php instead of url in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'd like to know if it'd be possible to put php lines instead of an url in this kind of script ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(window).scroll(function(){
   var mostOfTheWayDown = ($(document).height() - $(window).height()) * 9/10;
   if ($(window).scrollTop() >= mostOfTheWayDown) {
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "load.php", <--- here replace the line by
         url: "<?php do stuff ?>", <-- this one
         success: function(html){
         if(html){
         $(".sons").append(html);
         } else{
         }
         setTimeout(function() {
         // do stuff
         }, 1000);
     }
    });
   }
});
</script>
```

I'd like to do this thing because it's difficult to transmit vars created in the index.php to the load.php page.
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: `url: "<?php echo 'load.php'; ?>",`, did I misread the question?

Comment: Url has to be a url. You can print the url from php like Loz said, but it has to be a url not code. If that's not what you want, you shouldn't be using Ajax.

Comment: @scrowler how can I do that ?

Comment: @developerwjk here's the situation : I've got an index.php that parse a json file and fill in many arrays. It, then, echo those datas in the page, but there's too many so I thought of doing a script that calls a function which loads 10 datas per 10 datas, but I don't know how to give to the script the very first arrays I created, I tried with $_SESSION but it did'nt work well. So I wanted to put php lines in the ajax url in order to user the present arrays.

Comment: Don't expect the PHP to load Asynchronously, like that. It will load as soon as the page does.

Comment: You can pass a parameter like first index of array through ajax with a `data:` section, and then use that in the arrays (put the arrays in the file called by ajax rather than in index).

Comment: @developerwjk THANK'S ! :D how doest it work ? I pass mutiple $arrays with data, and in my php file I just use those $arrays ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely. You're just using PHP to preprocess the JavaScript the same way you'd use it to preprocess HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(window).scroll(function(){
   var mostOfTheWayDown = ($(document).height() - $(window).height()) * 9/10;
   if ($(window).scrollTop() >= mostOfTheWayDown) {
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "load.php", <--- here replace the line by
         url: "<?php echo $url; ?>", // arbitrary URL string
         success: function(html){
         if(html){
         $(".sons").append(html);
         } else{
         }
         setTimeout(function() {
         // do stuff
         }, 1000);
     }
    });
   }
});
</script>
```

But keep in mind that when doing this, once PHP finishes executing on the server and the response is sent, the client's web browser will only be executing the resulting JavaScript. PHP will not continue to update it after its initial execution.